# Access SAP GUI for a linux

Tags: sap-gui

I have SAP installed on linux and SAP GUI is on Windows.

For the SAP setups that are installed on windows, I had installed Webdynpro and I am able to access them with the GUI. But for linux, I am not sure what configuration has to be done for SAP GUI to enable access.

Comment: What else would you want to access Web (!) Dynpro applications besides a browser?

Comment: Question is specifically for linux... I am a novice and pretty much clue less about the Configuration steps etc... Do you mean to say Web Dynpro can be installed for non windows also ?

Comment: Do you mean the design tools for WebDynpro (accessed from transaction SE80 in the case of ABAP, Eclipse in the case of Java) or WebDynpro runtime access, which is rendered via a web browser? If the runtime, the OS won't matter (ignoring browser compatibility issues here). If the design time, unfortunately it only works on Windows systems as the controls are not available in the JavaGUI/Eclipse on a non-Windows platform.

Answer (score 2):

*WebDynpro* (ABAP) is a proprietary declarative programming language which runs on the ABAP application server (and is Operating system independent). Typically Web Dynpro applications are most commonly accessed via web browser i.e. a client does not have to have SAP Gui (the client) installed to view and access them, although technically it is possible to view Web Dynpro applications via the GUI (it is just an embedded web view).

In order to view applications typically you need to enable a set of services of the Internet Communication Framework (ICF) as well as ensure that the host name of the server is configured correctly (should operate on a fully qualified domain name) - which is set up in the instance profile (transaction RZ10).

So in summary your OS should not influence whether you can access an Web Dynpro application or not, rather your SAP system settings.